# Accessing response.json data arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch

I've looked everywhere but cannot find the answer for this problem.

RAWG is a game review website now with their own API (instead of using Rapid API) and I want data for "Tom Clancy Rainbow Six Siege".

I convert the data returned from the request into a response.json (using the code below) but I cannot access the game "Tom Clancy Rainbow Six Siege".

```
fetch("https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=[KEY]&developers=ubisoft", {
    method: 'GET'
})

// Gets the response from the website
.then(response => response.json())
// Uses the data in the json to populate the website with information
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  for (const game in data.results) {
    if (game == 6) {
        console.log(game[0]['id']);
    }
  }
});
```

API return (this is from console.log):

```
{count: 305, next: 'https://api.rawg.io/api/games?developers=ubisoft&key=[key]&page=2', previous: null, results: Array(20), user_platforms: false}
count: 305
next: "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?developers=ubisoft&key=[key]&page=2"
previous: null
results: Array(20)
0: {slug: 'far-cry-3', name: 'Far Cry 3', playtime: 16, platforms: Array(5), stores: Array(4), …}
1: {slug: 'for-honor', name: 'For Honor', playtime: 7, platforms: Array(3), stores: Array(4), …}
2: {slug: 'watch-dogs', name: 'Watch Dogs', playtime: 19, platforms: Array(6), stores: Array(6), …}
3: {slug: 'far-cry-5', name: 'Far Cry 5', playtime: 19, platforms: Array(3), stores: Array(3), …}
4: {slug: 'assassins-creed-odyssey', name: "Assassin's Creed Odyssey", playtime: 32, platforms: Array(4), stores: Array(5), …}
5: {slug: 'assassins-creed-origins', name: "Assassin's Creed Origins", playtime: 35, platforms: Array(3), stores: Array(3), …}
6: {slug: 'rayman-legends', name: 'Rayman Legends', playtime: 5, platforms: Array(8), stores: Array(6), …}
7:
added: 5061
added_by_status: {yet: 93, owned: 3811, beaten: 244, toplay: 56, dropped: 533, …}
background_image: "https://media.rawg.io/media/games/b34/b3419c2706f8f8dbe40d08e23642ad06.jpg"
clip: null
dominant_color: "0f0f0f"
esrb_rating: {id: 3, name: 'Teen', slug: 'teen', name_en: 'Teen', name_ru: 'С 13 лет'}
genres: (2) [{…}, {…}]
id: 8488
metacritic: 75
name: "Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege"
parent_platforms: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
platforms: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
playtime: 29
rating: 3.99
rating_top: 4
ratings: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
ratings_count: 1076
released: "2015-12-01"
reviews_count: 1085
reviews_text_count: 5
saturated_color: "0f0f0f"
score: null
short_screenshots: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
slug: "tom-clancys-rainbow-six-siege-2"
stores: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
suggestions_count: 466
tags: (16) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
tba: false
updated: "2021-02-17T15:00:09"
user_game: null
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I want to access #7 (Rainbow six siege) and get the id and name. But for the life of me I can't figure it out. The `for` loop just returns the number `6`, and I can't access any data inside this.

Comment: How do you know that information is going to be at that array index? Surely you must at least know the title so you can search for it. Also you need to `JSON.parse(data)` and _then_ iterate over the `results` property.

Comment: I search by title, slug, and id. But for some reason the API can't find any results for these parameters.

Comment: Also, By searching "Ubisoft", the game i want is always at this array index

Comment: You can search for that specific title by simply adding `&search=Rainbow six siege` to the end of the URL [as per the API documentation](https://api.rawg.io/docs/#operation/games_list).

Comment: @Andy Oh.. I looked at the documentation and did not see that. It works, but it still returns the same array results as above when I do response.json().
I cannot access the data in `0: {slug: 'tom-clancys-rainbow-six-siege-2' etc.}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, with a bit of digging I came up with this.

Your search parameters should be `search=` the title you're looking for, and `search_exact` which should be `true`.

```
search=tom-clancys-rainbow-six-siege&search_exact=true
```

It should return data of count 1, and you can access the information in the object of the first `results` array element.

```js
const url = 'https://api.rawg.io/api/games?developers=ubisoft&key={your key}&search=tom-clancys-rainbow-six-siege&search_exact=true';

async function getData() {
  const json = await fetch(url);
  const data = await json.json();
  const { id, name } = data.result[0];
  console.log(id, name);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much for the help!
Also, I found in the API I can do `https://api.rawg.io/api/games/{GameID}?key{APIkey}` and it returns just results without so many arrays.